# Merging Arrays Created using Google Drive NextPageToken Into a Single Array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have the following code that downloads files from Google Drive, the number of which is determined by the nextPageToken, as per the following code.

The code will continue adding arrays to the $files array until the nextPageToken is null.   At which point I have an unknown number of sub arrays which I would like to merge into a single array without the need to loop through all the returned arrays - is there a simple way of doing this with PHP?

So, in the code below I would like $files[] to be a single array.  For example:

`$result = array_merge($files);`  just produces the same result

````
```
  $nextPageToken = "empty" ;
  while ( $nextPageToken != null) {
    $responseFiles = $drive->ListFiles( $optParams);
    $nextPageToken = $responseFiles->getNextPageToken();
    $files[]  = $responseFiles->getFiles();
    $optParams = array(
        'fields' => "nextPageToken, files(contentHints/thumbnail,fileExtension,iconLink,id,name,size,thumbnailLink,webContentLink,webView Link,mimeType,parents)",
        'q' => "'".$match[0]."' in parents",
        'pageToken' => $nextPageToken,
        'orderBy' => 'modifiedTime desc, name'
        );

   
  }
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty `$files` array before your loop and then merge and return with every loop like below.

```php
$files = [];
$nextPageToken = "empty";

$optParams = array(
    'fields' => "nextPageToken, files(contentHints/thumbnail,fileExtension,iconLink,id,name,size,thumbnailLink,webContentLink,webView Link,mimeType,parents)",
    'pageToken' => $nextPageToken,
    'orderBy' => 'modifiedTime desc, name'
);

while ( $nextPageToken != null) {
  $responseFiles = $drive->ListFiles($optParams);
  $nextPageToken = $responseFiles->getNextPageToken();
  $files = array_merge($files, $responseFiles->getFiles());
  $optParams['q'] => "'".$match[0]."' in parents";
}
```

Check out the api doc for [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for more info.

Comment: Ahh... perfect.  I was assuming that I would do the merge at the end, rather than during the download loop.  Thankyou.